# Get first post of an Instagram user

Tags: instagram

I was wondering if there was a way to download the FIRST post a user has ever posted on Instagram using the Instagram API, specifically the /users/{user-id}/media/recent endpoint. I could easily do this by paginating through all of the user's media, but this could take an especially long time for users with many posts, or users with pictures that have many likes or comments. So, is there any way to download the very first post, or the chunk of posts containing the first one?

I'm doing this because I need to get the date that the first image was posted in order to calculate an average posts per day value (number of posts / days since first post was posted). If there is an easier way of doing so, please let me know!

Thank you for your help!
Elliott

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You the user/media/recent api with `max_timestamp`:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/55431/media/recent/?max_timestamp=1292304000&client_id=
```

call the API with different `max_timestamp` value for last 3 years using bubble sort, if the response has `data` and does not have a `pagination` value, then get the last image object in the response, this will be the very first image.

---

Instagram has been around since last 3 years I think, get timestamp for a year and half ago and make an API call:

IF there is no `data` in response, then go to newer time and make API call and check response.

IF there is `data` in response and has `pagination` value, then make another API call with older time and check response.

IF there is `data` in response and has no `pagination` value in API response, then get the last image object in this response, this is your first image!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any idea of the instagram API, but I thought I could share some general thoughts. If the instagram API does not provide a way to find the date of the first post, you can calculate an approximate average in the following way :

1. Count the number of post in last month, previous month and so on backwards for as long as possible.
2. Try fitting the number of posts per month to a trend.
3. Calculate the approximate average from the trend.

Comment: That's a great idea! I was thinking of doing something of the sort if I couldn't find the date of the user's first post. Thanks for your help :)